# limit of sequence of functions not differentiable at some point

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

If $(f_n)$ is differentiable on $R$ and both $(f_n)$ and $(f'_n)$ converge uniformly then can the limit of $(f_n)$ not be differentiable at some point?

My attempt is $(f_n) = \frac{1}{x + \frac{1}{n}}$ but in order for it to be uniformly convergent to $\frac{1}{x}$ the domain must be $[1,\infty)$ so $0$ where the discontinuity would be is not in the domain.

Help appreciated.

Comment: If $(f_n)_n$ converges uniformly then its pointwise limit $f$ is a continuous function. If further $(f'_n)_n$ converges uniformly then $f$ is differentiable.

Answer (score 1):

No, you guess is wrong due the following result from Rudin 
[image]